# AlwaysOn availability group listener

Tags: sql-server-2019, disaster-recovery, availability-groups

There is a server with me that is already configured with AlwaysOn by somebody else. I am adding one more availability group to the server. Can I use the same availability group  listener for the new configuration?

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn’t make any sense, where would the listener name point to if you had one Availability Group with a primary replica in instance A and the other Availability Group with a primary replica in instance B?

New AG = New AG Listener

If you want to share the listener then you have to share the Availability Group (and that is possible to have multiple databases under the same Group, at least in Enterprise Edition).